# Convert int, long, boolean, String, double in List (two variants), Set(two variants), Queue, Deque

Tags: java, arrays, generics, collections

I have a method to convert an array to an ArrayList as follows:

```
public class Main {

    //https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html
    public static <T> void fromArrayToCollection(T[] a, Collection<T> c) {
        for (T o : a) {
            c.add(o);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Car [] cars = new Car[2];
        cars[0] = new Car(1, "Volvo", "2612AXA");
        cars[1] = new Car(2, "Toyota", "1861AXA");

        int [] i = new int[2];
        i[0] = 1;
        i[1] = 1;

        long [] l = new long[2];
        l[0] = 122342141;
        l[1] = 214214211;

        double [] d = new double[2];
        d[0] = 1.0;
        d[1] = 2.0;

        boolean [] b = new boolean[2];
        b[0] = true;
        b[1] = false;

        String [] s = new String[2];
        s[0] = "One";
        s[1] = "Two";

        Collection<String> sc = new ArrayList<String>();
        fromArrayToCollection(s, sc);
        System.out.println(sc);

    }
}
```

It is easy to convert other types of array. But i have some class with three fields.

```
public class Car {
    int id;
    String car_name;
    String number;

    public Car(int id, String car_name, String number) {
        this.id = id;
        this.car_name = car_name;
        this.number = number;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Car{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", car_name='" + car_name + '\'' +
                ", number='" + number + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

How convert array cars into collection ? And how convert into collections my all arrays using iterator? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you correctly. You can convert the car array the same way, as you already pointed out yourself: `Collection<Car> cc = new ArrayList<Car>();  fromArrayToCollection(cars, cc);` You are already using an iterator by using the for construct with the colon (:) - internally, this is done by using the array's iterator, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html

Comment: Or you can use `java.util.Arrays.toList()` method instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I don't think your `fromArrayToCollection` method will work for primitive arrays. You can't have a `Collection<int>` and a `Collection<Integer> will bind `T[]` to `Integer[]` and not to `int[]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Car[] carsArray = new Car[2];

... 

List<Car> listOfCars = Arrays.asList(carsArray);
```